# Postgresql, using Copy function to export results to XML file

Tags: xml, postgresql, postgresql-copy

I have written some SQL functions which output XML results. Since the output size is big, I need to write them directly to a xml file. To this I'm using COPY function as follows:

```
COPY(SELECT generate_xml_file()) TO '/Users/TEMP/test.xml'
```

But the problem with this is, then generated file has \n character at the end of every tag. I tried to use the following options to eliminate '\n' but it didn't work:

```
 COPY(SELECT generate_xml_file()) TO '/Users/TEMP/test.xml' WITH NULL AS ' '
```

Is there any facility provided in Postgresql to get this done?

Comment: show the function or even better build db-fiddle - I cant reproduce the issue - `with null as ' ' `works for me

Comment: copy(select XMLSERIALIZE( content xmlelement(name test, query_to_xml('select * from tb2', false, true, '')) as text)) TO '/Users/TEMP/test.xml' WITH NULL AS ' '       

I'm using XMLSERIALIZE to perform some string operations. and the output is also in 'text' type.

Comment: Here is the result:      <test><row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">\n  <col3>1</col3>\n  <col4>1</col4>\n</row>\n\n<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">\n  <col3>2</col3>\n  <col4>2</col4>\n</row>\n\n<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">\n  <col3>3</col3>\n  <col4>3</col4>\n</row>\n\n<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">\n  <col3>4</col3>\n  <col4>4</col4>\n</row>\n\n<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">\n  <col3>5</col3>\n  <col4>5</col4>\n</row>\n\n</test>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `\n` is for new line, not null. If you use default tsv mode - each new line is represented as `\n` to distinguish difference between new line and new row, eg:

```
t=# copy(select query_to_xml('select datname,null blah from pg_database limit 2',false,true,'')) to stdout;
<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">\n  <datname>postgres</datname>\n</row>\n\n<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">\n  <datname>t</datname>\n</row>\n\n
```

So simply csv option will rescue you, eg:

```
t=# copy(select query_to_xml('select datname,null blah from pg_database limit 2',false,true,'')) to stdout csv;
"<row xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">
  <datname>postgres</datname>
</row>

<row xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">
  <datname>t</datname>
</row>

"
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

> COPY TO will terminate each row with a Unix-style newline (“\n”).

and so on...

**update**

copying to stdout or file does not matter:

```
t=# copy(select query_to_xml('select datname,null blah from pg_database limit 2',false,true,'')) to '/tmp/sp.xml' csv;
COPY 1
Time: 0.481 ms
t=# \! cat /tmp/sp.xml
"<row xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">
  <datname>postgres</datname>
</row>

<row xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">
  <datname>t</datname>
</row>

"
```

Comment: But this will not write the result to a file?

Comment: I use `to stdout` to show the result. change to '/path/to/file' and you have it in file, or redirect psql to a file with proper formatting

Comment: That's what I did, used copy(select XMLSERIALIZE( content xmlelement(name test, query_to_xml('select * from tb2', false, true, '')) as text)) TO '/Users/TEMP/test.xml''. But the problem was having \n in the result.

Comment: I updated the answer demonstrating that copy destination does not change the result

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the double quotes `"..."` around the result? Also, there are double quotes around every xml string. That can't be valid can it?

Comment: those are not around xml string but around a csv  "column" value. notice tsv has no such effect (while it adds `\n` what OP wanted to escape). in other words - this is CSV requirement I assume